# base64 hash using HMAC SHA256

Tags: apex, crypto, base64, encodingutil, hashcode

**I am trying to compute the Apex equivalent of the following -**

```
var shaBodyContent = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(stringToSign, postman.getEnvironmentVariable("HMAC_SS"));

var b64BodyContent = shaBodyContent.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

**Apex:**

```
    Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256',blob.valueOf(stringToSign),blob.valueOf(secretAccessKey));
    system.debug('This is the shaBodyContent: ' +mac); // debug log displays Blob[32]

    String signature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
    system.debug(This is b64BodyContent :' +signature);
```

This, system.debug('This is the shaBodyContent: ' +mac); displays **Blob[32]** and this, system.debug(This is b64BodyContent :' +signature);  displays a string

However when I create a raw signature as follows -

```
    String authorization_header = 'RouteOne' + ' ' + accessKeyID + ':' + signature;
```

I get an error.

**Status Code:** 401

**Status Message:** Unauthorized

**Error Message:** "The authenticity of the request could not be verified","developerMessage":"The HMAC-SHA256 headers encoded with the secret key associated with the Access Key Id provided did not match the encoded value provided in the request Authorization header"

Comment: Is the value of `b64bodyContent` in JS same as the value of `signature` in Apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> system.debug('This is the shaBodyContent: ' +mac); // debug log displays Blob[32]
> ```

Yes, this is what Blob does when you "debug" it. The output says that it is a binary data object that is 32 bytes in size. To see the *actual* contents, use `EncodingUtil.convertToHex` or `EncodingUtil.base64Encode`:

```
System.debug('This is the shaBodyContent in hex: '+EncodingUtil.convertToHex(mac));
System.debug('This is the shaBodyContent in base64: '+EncodingUtil.base64encode(mac));
```

The latter value *should* match what you see in JS. If not, you've used the wrong key *or* you formatted the string incorrectly. Working with binary data in Apex is rather non-trivial because of its limited support for binary.

Comment: Thanks @SFDCFOX. Most likely I have formatted the string incorrectly.